# Rewrite url with .htacess doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess

I have a link

http://www.mydomain.com/place/index.php?slug=antalya-hotels

and i want to write this like

http://www.mydomain.com/place/antalya-hotels.html

I have tried this

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /place/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Bu didnt work. how we can do.

Comment: Try `^place/([^/]*)\.html$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^place/([^.]+)\.html$ /place/index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /$1/index.php?slug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```